# PhantomJS Web Server vs Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

Whats the difference here? I want to create a small API for queueing jobs, but I am not sure which should I be using. I'm leaning towards just using Node, but I do understand what is the point of having a web server module for PhantomJS.

Comment: What jobs do you want to queue, phantomjs scripts?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, but I would still have to run a job system like Kue right?

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?  I'm looking at doing something similar and am wondering if using node has an advantage over the built in webserver.

Comment: @TWilly There isn't an inherent advantage for using Node as a webserver. If you use Node, the issue is you have two JavaScript environments which may be confusing for some developers. You also have to start/manage the PhantomJS process from Node. So I would suggest using whatever has better process/daemon management for your webserver. 

Curious, but what are you working on?

Answer (score 1):

From the [PhantomJS docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/), the Phantom webserver is still experimental and intended to manage other phantom scripts and provide an interface to those scripts from the web. It currently only supports up to 10 concurrent requests. I'd recommend using node if you are looking for a general purpose web server.